# During UserCreationForm, id does not register into system

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

First of all, it's my error code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/202as.jpg

In my Django Project, need to register a doctor account. Every doctor has a 'hospital.' So, Doctor model has a hospital as a Foreign Key.

```
class Doctor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='isim')
    gsm = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    hospital = models.ForeignKey(Hospitals, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Hospitals(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    province = models.ForeignKey(Province, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    district = models.ForeignKey(District, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    numBeds = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    numRooms = models.CharField(max_length=5)
```

```
class UserRegisterForm2(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email address')
    email2 = forms.EmailField(label='Confirm Email')
    hospital = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=[(x.id, x.name) for x in Hospitals.objects.all()]
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'email',
            'email2',
            'hospital'

        ]

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        email2 = self.cleaned_data.get('email2')
        if email != email2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Emails must match")
        email_qs = User.objects.filter(email=email)
        if email_qs.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "This email has already been registered")
        return super(UserRegisterForm2, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'hospital':
            return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super().save(commit=False)
        pk = self.cleaned_data['hospital']
        instance.hospital = Hospitals.objects.get(pk=pk)
        instance.save(commit)
        return instance
```

When i go to the registration page, I can see the hospitals registered in the database. Like it's a photo of it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpEo4.jpg
But when I try to register after completing the required parts, I get the error I told you about. (column hospital_id cannot be null) I guess, i can pull hospitals names in the database; but i can not save it's id. How can i do that?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: So, i change the ChoiceField to ModelChoiceField like this:

```
hospital = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Hospitals.objects.all(), initial=0)
```

But this time, i get an error like this:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'ModelBase'
```

Edit2: I made an other change.

```
hospital = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Hospitals.objects.values_list('name', flat=True), to_field_name="id")
```

So far so good, I can enter the site, I can access the registration section: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1u3V.jpg
It says, "Select a valid choice." What does this even mean? I can show all my hospitals (only 1 right now) and i can select it, but when i click signup button: it's says same error over and over again.

Comment: You should use a ModelChoiceField instead of a ChoiceField. The current way that you have your form configured will mean that any new/deleted/updated hospitals will not be reflected in the form as you have created the choices the first time your form is loaded. This is bad for many reasons other than you not getting any updates - start-up time being one of them

Comment: So, i change it like this:                                                                                     
hospital = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Hospitals.objects.all(), initial=0) But in this way, i get an error message: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Hospitals' How can i filter ONLY hospital ids??